# I am using provide/inject to pass the data within components , I've this function using compute, I am trying to run and pass it's result in provide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex

I have 4 functions, for 1st three functions, I can send the data in provide. For 4th function(

```
getViewApplicationDetails
```

), I am trying to fetch api and get application name, now I want that in mounted because, I want the application name as soon as component is rendered so I am trying to execute it in mounted but when I call the it, it's giving me error. Initially application name is empty and it should have the current application name when I fetch the api, the same application name will be used in provide and then I can use that in inject and then in any other component.

```
import { computed, inject, onMounted, provide, reactive } from "vue";

export const initStore = () => {
  onMounted(()=>{
  this.getViewApplicationDetails()
  });
  // State
  const state = reactive({
    name: "Bob Day",
    email: "bob@martianmovers.com",
    applicationName: "",
    breadcrumbsData: [
      {
          name: "Home",
          text: 'Home',
          disabled: false,
          href: '/'
      }
    ]
  });
  // Getters
  const getUsername = computed(() => state.name);
  const getEmail = computed(() => console.log("state.email",state.email));
  const getBreadcrumbsData=computed(()=>state.breadcrumbsData)
  console.log("state.applicationName",state.applicationName)
  //this is the temporary function
  const getApplicationName=computed(()=>state.applicationName)
  const getViewApplicationDetails=computed(()=> {
    var viewApplicationDetailsParams = {
        applicationId: this.$route.query.applicationId,
        applicationStatus:this.$route.query.appStatus,
        authType: "api",
        clientId: process.env.VUE_APP_EXTERNAL_API_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.VUE_APP_EXTERNAL_API_CLIENT_SECRET                
    };
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: process.env.VUE_APP_BLUJ_BACKEND_URL + "/viewapplicationDefinition",
        data: viewApplicationDetailsParams,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
    })
        .then((response) =>{
          this.viewDefinitionResponse = response.data.Definitions;
          let applicationName = viewDefinitionResponse.application_display_name.en;
          console.log("tyfgyhkjlfhgjklnm",applicationName)
          setApplicationName(applicationName)
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        });
});
getViewApplicationDetails()
  // Mutations
  const setUsername = (name) => {
    state.name = name;
  };
  const setEmail = (email) => {
    state.email = email;
  };

  const setBreadCrumbsData=(breadcrumbsData)=>{
    state.breadcrumbsData=breadcrumbsData;
  }
  const setApplicationName=(appName)=>{
    state.applicationName=appName
  }
  // Actions
  const updateUsername = (name) => {
    setUsername(name);
  };
  const updateEmail = (email) => {
    setEmail(email);
  };


  provide("getUsername", getUsername);
  provide("getEmail", getEmail);
  provide("updateUsername", updateUsername);
  provide("updateEmail", updateEmail);
  provide("getViewApplicationDetails", getViewApplicationDetails);   
  provide("getApplicationName", getApplicationName);
  provide("getBreadcrumbsData", getBreadcrumbsData);
};

export const useStore = () => ({
  getUsername: inject("getUsername"),
  getEmail: inject("getEmail"),
  updateUsername: inject("updateUsername"),
  updateEmail: inject("updateEmail"),
  viewApplicationDetails: inject("getViewApplicationDetails"),
  getBreadcrumbsData: inject("getBreadcrumbsData"),
  getApplicationName: inject("getApplicationName")
});
```

This is the code snippet.

```
  const getUsername = computed(() => state.name);
  const getEmail = computed(() => console.log("state.email",state.email));
  const getBreadcrumbsData=computed(()=>state.breadcrumbsData)
```

I am getting data for this, but for getViewApplicationDetails, it's not working. While hovering over rest of the functions, it is showing "const getUsername: ComputedRef", like this. But, for getViewApplicationDetails, it shows "const getViewApplicationDetails: ComputedRef", this. I think it is not taking it as function or something. Error image is in the link.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytqIa.png)

Comment: Please, paste error messages as is, this helps. It's really not a function, there's no proper `this` in arrow functions, you shouldn't use `this` with composition api at all. Even without `this`, it's still not a function, it's a computed. You shouldn't do requests in computeds, this is not how they work. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there seems to be a component and state pasted together.

Comment: I guess, it would make sense to study the vue documentation first and learn a bit about how the composition API works and also make sure to understand what the error is about. You will learn a lot by that. I think just pasting a whole code and just ask "why is that not working" is not easy to answer. As @EstusFlask points out, the way you use computed values seems like you haven’t understand how it works.  Computed values are reactive properties, not functions so naming them with the prefix `get` does not make sense at all.